# how to get any old version of a repository without losing commit history

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am practising how to use github, and I get any old version of the repository *without losing commit history*. How to do that?

The issue is that If I do git reset *commit id* --hard, I do get the specific version of repository but the commit history get deleted. I want to get a specific version of the repository but I dont want to lose the commit history

Comment: `git checkout <hash>`?

Comment: When you want to go to an old commit, there is no need to reset. You can use `git checkout the-commit-id` (old way) or `git switch the-commit-id` (newish way).

Comment: so when I do git checkout *commit id*  , I do go to old version but I am unable to push this into main branch, any idea where the issue could be?

Comment: What do you mean "push this into the main branch"? What are you trying to _do_ with this old commit?

Comment: i want to continue working with the old commit which is why I want to push it into the main branch

Comment: So you want it to become the head of the branch? In that case why did you think resetting to it wasn't correct?

Comment: becuase if later I think that the old version of repository wasnt neccesary and the repository before getting old version of it was needed, I would still need my commit history to be intact

Comment: So create a new branch with that history before resetting `main`.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard <blob>` does not immediately "delete the history" on your machine. Use `git log --oneline --all --graph --reflog` to view every blob. You can use `git reset --hard <blob>` to return to a commit.

Branching off of a blob before a hard reset will also give you an easy way to return to that blob by using `git switch <branch>`